# Templated class const qualifier constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, binary-tree

I'm having trouble creating a new object by "copying" an already existent object of the same type.

```
template<class dataType>
inline Node<dataType>::Node(const Node<dataType> & node)
{
    if (this != nullptr)
    {
        this->mData = node.getData();
        this->mLeft = node.getLeft();
        this->mRight = node.getRight();
    }
}
```

Should I be using the above? Or should I just do:

```
template<class dataType>
    inline Node<dataType>::Node(const Node<dataType> & node)
    {
        this = node;
    }
```

The latter yields the next error:

```
1>h:\projects\binary search trees\data\classes\node.h(51): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const Node<float> *' to 'Node<float> *const '
1>  h:\projects\binary search trees\data\classes\node.h(51): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

The former complains about something similar:

```
1>h:\projects\binary search trees\data\classes\node.h(51): error C2662: 'float Node<float>::getData(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Node<float>' to 'Node<float> &'
1>  h:\projects\binary search trees\data\classes\node.h(51): note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No, Node<T> only contains T mData and 2 pointers to Node<T> objects. This is my attempt at binary trees implementation. The compiler generated constructor does work. However, the purpose of this is learning. So I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What do you want your copy constructor to do? Just copy the pointers, or perform a deep copy of the entire tree from that node down?

Comment: I want it to copy the pointers and the data, as the pointers already have the left and right sub-trees stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you somewhere have already defined assignment operator, you can use

```
template<class dataType>
    inline Node<dataType>::Node(const Node<dataType> & node)
    {
        *this = node;
    }
```

to reuse its code and don't repeat yourself.
The `*` means dereferencing `this` pointer. But your assign operator must take into account it can be called for default constructed value as lvalue.